# I face this problem with building gradle , how can I fix it?

Tags: android, flutter, maven, gradle, maven-2

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not find sdk-common-30.1.2.jar (com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.1.2).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/sdk-common/30.1.2/sdk-common-30.1.2.jar
> Could not find repository-30.1.2.jar (com.android.tools:repository:30.1.2).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/repository/30.1.2/repository-30.1.2.jar
> Could not find gradle-api-7.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:7.1.2).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle-api/7.1.2/gradle-api-7.1.2.jar
> Could not find builder-test-api-7.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder-test-api:7.1.2).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder-test-api/7.1.2/builder-test-api-7.1.2.jar
> Could not find ddmlib-30.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.ddms:ddmlib:30.1.2).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/ddms/ddmlib/30.1.2/ddmlib-30.1.2.jar
> Could not find aaptcompiler-7.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.build:aaptcompiler:7.1.2).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aaptcompiler/7.1.2/aaptcompiler-7.1.2.jar
> Could not find bundletool-1.8.0.jar (com.android.tools.build:bundletool:1.8.0).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/bundletool/1.8.0/bundletool-1.8.0.jar
> Could not find aapt2-proto-7.1.2-7984345.jar (com.android.tools.build:aapt2-proto:7.1.2-7984345).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2-proto/7.1.2-7984345/aapt2-proto-7.1.2-7984345.jar
> Could not find crash-30.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:crash:30.1.2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
flutter clean
dart pub get
flutter pub get
flutter run
```

If this not resolved the problem, try deleting **app/build** folder & or **app/android/app/build** folder

Answer (score 1):

If you are in one of the countries banned by Google, you have to use a VPN. And if you're in Iran, use the Shecan DNS. It's the best option. And you probably have to delete the .gradle cache folder or create a new project if you want it to be applied to this project.